# How to query a entity based on an related entity property in TypeORM?

Tags: typeorm

I have an Entity `Transaction` and an Entity `Integration`

```
@Entity()
export default class Transaction {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id_trans?: number;

    @OneToOne(type => Integration, i => i.transaction, { nullable: true })
    public integration?: Integration;
}
```

and

```
@Entity()
export default class Integration {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id_cust?: number;

    @OneToOne(type => Transaction, t => t.integration)
    @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'id_trans', name: 'int_id_module' })
    public transaction?: Transaction;
}
```

I tried to query the Transaction by using a Integration property as filter.

```
const id_api = 10;
const transaction = await repository.find({
        where: { integration: { int_id_api: id_api} },
        relations: ['integration', 'customer'],
    });
```

but it returns the entire table of Transactions, even if the `integration.int_id_api` is different from `id_api` property

What am I doing wrong. What should I do to get this query working ?

Comment: Not sure how this factors into the solution to your question, but doesn't your Integration class need a primary key?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a primary key to all your entities. [From the doc](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm#creating-a-primary-column):

> Each entity **must** have at least one primary key column. This is a
>   requirement and **you can't avoid it**. To make a column a primary key,
>   you need to use @PrimaryColumn decorator.

Assuming you update the `Integration` entity like so

```
@Entity()
export default class Integration {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    public id_inte: number;

    @OneToOne(type => Transaction, t => t.integration)
    @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'id_trans', name: 'int_id_module' })
    public transaction?: Transaction;
}
```

You should be able to find transactions like so

```
const transaction = await repository.find({
    where: { integration: { id_inte: some_id } },
    relations: ['integration', 'customer'],
});
```